# Switch to dart 2 causes issue for jaguar serializer

Tags: flutter

Through the update to dart 2 the jaguar serializer causes problems.

My settings are:

Flutter Channel **beta, v0.2.8**

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  analyzer: "^0.31.2-alpha.1" ## i also tried to get the newest version
  intl: "^0.15.4"
  http: "^0.11.3+16"
  great_circle_distance: "^1.0.1"
  ####jaguar_serializer: "^1.0.0-dev5"
  jaguar_serializer: ^1.0.0-dev1

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^0.8.0
  jaguar_serializer_cli: ^1.0.0-dev1
```

This is the error message i got. It seems like the analyzer package has changed..

DynamicTypeImpl is from package:analyzer/**src/dart**/element/type.dart

InterfaceType is from package:analyzer/**dart**/element/type.dart

```
  [SEVERE] jaguar_serializer_cli on lib/foundation/dart/logic/raw/RawType.dart:
    Error running JaguarSerializerGenerator for nalisa_foundation|lib/foundation/dart/logic/raw/RawType.dart.
    type 'DynamicTypeImpl' is not a subtype of type 'InterfaceType' in type cast where
      DynamicTypeImpl is from package:analyzer/src/dart/element/type.dart
      InterfaceType is from package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart

    [SEVERE] jaguar_serializer_cli on lib/foundation/dart/logic/Status.dart:
    Error running JaguarSerializerGenerator for nalisa_foundation|lib/foundation/dart/logic/Status.dart.
    type 'DynamicTypeImpl' is not a subtype of type 'InterfaceType' in type cast where
      DynamicTypeImpl is from package:analyzer/src/dart/element/type.dart
      InterfaceType is from package:analyzer/dart/element/type.dart
```

Comment: I'd create an issue in the packages GitHub Repo

Comment: yep i will do it

Answer (score 0):

Use jaguar_serialzier `2.2`.

```
dependencies:
  analyzer: "^0.32.0"
  intl: "^0.15.4"
  http: "^0.11.3+16"
  great_circle_distance: "^1.0.1"
  jaguar_serializer: ^2.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^0.8.0
  jaguar_serializer_cli: ^2.2.0
```

Also, Jaguar gitter channel is a good place to ask questions.